# Sematics Question for People Who Know About SSL certificates

Tags: terminology

I'm looking to get some quick, informal feedback about some copy we may use in our UI.

If you're familiar with SSL certificates, can you read the copy below and let me know your thoughts?

Copy:
"Build trust with your customers—apply a custom SSL certificate"

Comment: This falls under the category of site review, and should be closed as the answers will be primarily subjective are only really valuable to the person asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Meaningless

**TL;DR Every SSL certificate is custom at the most basic level. And beyond that, virtually nobody knows or cares.**

**Every** SSL certicicate is "custom" in that it references the domain name, and possibly other web site/company specific data. But beyond those basics, which are, at least minimally, **required**, by the nature of a functioning SSL certificate, what else matters? An end-user looking at the site may notice a different color or whatever for a higher-level certification, but most people don't even notice that - or may notice but have no idea what it means. Anything else would be buried inside the details of the certificate - and almost nobody (except security professionals) looks at the details of a certificate unless the browser presents it as an error.

Personally, I've migrated wherever possible from Thawte and other high-level certificates to [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and nobody I know as an ordinary web *user* knows the difference.